# Iphone Link Static Library

Tags: iphone, static-libraries, static-linking

I have created a static library in XCode called TestLib.
I then created a simple test project that will use this library. I dragged the TestLib xcode project into my test project (frameworks section - if it matters), and set TestLib as a direct dependency of the test project.

I am having trouble importing header files from the Library, I only have 1 in there (its a test project) called TestLibHeader.h, but no matter how I attempt to import them, I get compile errors stating that the header file cannot be found.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: are you copying the header files in the new project or just referencing them?

Comment: Do I need to copy them in? I thought they would simply be compiled as part of the lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your build target where to look for the header files for a given build configuration.

in XCode 3.x

1. Double click on your build target.
2. Click on the `Build` tab.
3. Search for the build setting `Header Search Paths`
4. Set `Header Search Paths` to include the path the header files in your library project.

See the instructions for setting up [three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) as a dependency for a good example of these steps in action.